# How to make text disable or invisible in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have a message on the page to instruct the user to select at least five items. I want the message to go away once the user has selected five items.

```
<span class="message" data-bind="text: messageToChooseAtLeastFiveItems, disable: hasSelectedFiveItems"></span>
```

Inside the ViewModel I have set the value initially to `false` and when the user selects five items the value changes to `true`.

```
self.hasSelectedFiveItems = ko.observable(false);

gridUnredeemed.onSelectedRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e) {
    var hasFiveRecalc = gridUnredeemed.getSelectedRows().length >= 5;

    self.hasSelectedFiveItems(hasFiveRecalc);
});
```

Why is the text inside the span still appearing?

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/jkittell/x5xjncyp/

Comment: try using visible like this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/x5xjncyp/2/. cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should be doing like this

**View :**

```
<select multiple="true" data-bind="options:array,selectedOptions:selected"></select>
<span class="message" data-bind="text: messageToChooseAtLeastFiveItems, visible: hasSelectedFiveItems"></span>
<button data-bind="click: chooseFive">Choose Five Now</button>
<button data-bind="click: chooseLessThanFive">Choose Less Than Five</button>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self=this;
    self.array=ko.observableArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]);
    self.selected=ko.observableArray();
    self.messageToChooseAtLeastFiveItems = "Choose Five Foo";
    self.hasSelectedFiveItems = ko.observable(true);
    self.chooseFive = function () {
        self.hasSelectedFiveItems(false);
    }
    self.chooseLessThanFive = function () {
        self.hasSelectedFiveItems(true);
    }
    self.selected.subscribe(function(data){
        console.log(data.length);
        if(data.length >=5) { self.hasSelectedFiveItems(false);}
        else
        { self.hasSelectedFiveItems(true);}
    });

}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Working sample with DropDown and buttons **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/x5xjncyp/3/)**

Sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/x5xjncyp/2/)** using just buttons as per you fiddle

Using computed(as millimetric mendtioned) we can do like this check **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/x5xjncyp/4/)** best for this particulara scenario .

Comment: you might just want `self.hasSelectedFiveItems = ko.computed(function(){ return this.selected().length >= 5; }, self);` instead, it's a bit cleaner.  Also, in your `chooseFive` demonstration function, you should really set something like `self.selected([1,2,3,4,5,6])` to prove that it's working, not bypass the logic by setting the final observable.

Comment: @Milimetric i agree , it can be a touch cleaner .  i prefer user to select from the list so i didn't give a default selection & *not bypass the logic* i am not sure am i doing so  . can you be more elaborate .

Comment: Ok, here's my suggestion as an update to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x5xjncyp/4/ .  What I meant by bypassing the logic is, `this.hasSelectedFiveItems` should really only be set as a reaction to the length of the selected observable.  So, if you're using the buttons to show that your reaction is working, you should perform the *triggering* action and not the *resulting* change.  Does that make sense?  You're welcome to use my code to update your answer if you agree.  You did the work and should get the credit, I'm just a clean freak :)

Comment: I'm with @Millimetric... add that as an answer. That's what computed's are for.

Comment: ooh @Milimetric you misunderstood me i just kept that buttons as OP used them in the post (even i'm completely against it) . sure i will update your fiddle in my answer .